# how to build dynamic grid and binding to xaml using mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, grid

I'm planning a WPF application which will build dynamic grid with textblocks in the viewmodel and then refresh interface (xaml) with the new grid.

I've done the firts step, but i have problems to refresh the view with the new grid.

Is there any example code of how to bind the grid to the xaml that I can have a look at?? I really can't figure this out!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be approaching this slightly wrongly, hard to say from the question-

Generally to show a dynamic set of UI elements in MVVM you bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl to an ObservableCollection. The ItemsControl ItemsTemplate property converts the YourViewModel object into a UIElement which can be a TextBlock or whatever style you want.

So as an example:

```
// model
class Person
{
   public string Name {get; private set;}
}

// view model
class MainViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Person> People {get; private set;}
}

//view
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding MyMainViewModelObject}">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>/
    </ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

I havent tested that code, it is just to illustrate. There are other ways of dissecting the problem into MVVM, it all depends on the situation. You would have to give more details for us to help you out with that. Rarely in WPF is there a need to use code to create or add UI elements to other UIElements etc.

A point to note more along the exact lines of the question however is that an ItemsControl can either bind to a bunch of regular objects and use it's template to create UIElements from them, OR it can bind to a list of UIElements, in which case the template is not applied (sounds like this is the situation you have).

Comment: Thank you Guy. The problem is complicated to explain. I need to create a grid dinamically because i don´t know the number of rows/columns and also customize the cells with colors and context menus in some cases. All this procedure of creating the grid, i do in viewmodel. The only thing I need is to refresh the view with the created grid in the viewmodel.